# using crypto random bytes in node in async way

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

```
    exports.resetPassword =  async (req,res,next) =>{
        // crete a random token 
        let token;
        // we are using callback to to get in random bytes
        await crypto.randomBytes(32, (err, buf) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(`${buf.length} bytes of random data: ${buf.toString('hex')}`);
          token = buf.toString('hex')
        });

           console.log(token)  // printing undefined
}
```

I used async and await so that  it will lof after  execution of the function only  but it is printing undefined cannot figure what is going on

2) plese help me how to write in async format and why it is failing  inside crypto random bytes i can see the output when i print token

Comment: Await only works with functions that return Promises. It doesn't work with functions that accept callbacks. Use `util.promisify()` to wrap that function in a promise

Comment: great 

Thanks in documention it is mentioned that the method is asynchronus so i taught of using async